# Kotlin: Is it possible to use componentN operator in repeat?

Tags: kotlin, repeat

I am learning kotlin from hyperskill.

I am curious if it is possible to assign componentN operator to repeat function as in:

```
val (a, b, c) = repeat(3) { BigInteger(readLine()!!) }
```

I have tried extending some of my functions with the `componentN` operator but I have no idea how to do it with `repeat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`repeat` doesn't return anything, which means you cannot use this function for [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations).
 But you can use `Range` with `map`, `List` or `Array`:

```
val (a, b, c) = (1..3).map { BigInteger(readLine()!!) }
//or
val (a, b, c) = Array(3) { BigInteger(readLine()!!) }
```